# 1064, "check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '%d, %d, %s

Tags: mysql-python

I'm doing a program to get data from arduino, temperature, humidity and rain, but I can not get rain values ​​to be filled in the database.

```
try:
    lluvia =data['canLluvia']
    except KeyError:
        lluvia=None
    curs = db.cursor()
    curs.execute("INSERT INTO temps(fecha,hum,temp,lluvia)values(%d, %d, %s)("+str(data['humidity'])+","+str(data['temperature'])+",lluvia)")
    db.commit()
```

Answer (score 0):

You have combined prepared SQL statement syntax with direct statement syntax on line 6 - and also messed with the data types. If you want to pass `int` to the database because of the database column format, you should not cast them to `str` at all and stick with `int` instead.

This would work as expected - assuming `fecha` field is an auto_increment, you do not need to set it manually:

```
curs.execute("INSERT INTO temps(hum,temp,lluvia) VALUES(%d, %d, %s)", (int(data['humidity']), int(data['temperature']), lluvia))
```